# How to suspend an USB device?

Tags: debian, usb, suspend

I want to suspend a connected USB device at my pc manually. I tried the following instructions in Debian (Kernel 3.2.0).

`uname` output:

```
Linux debian7-dev-gnome 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I want to suspend the following device:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC

echo -n "1-0:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/hub/unbind //for suspend
echo -n "1-0:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/hub/bind //for resume
```

After the `unbind` function the device disappears from `lsusb`, but I'm not sure if it is in suspend or just removed from the system without loosing power supply.

How can I suspend the USB device #3 at bus #1?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `echo -n "suspend" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/hub/1-0:1.0/power/level`
to suspend the said usb device

Comment: That didn't work but [this](https://superuser.com/a/371254/1039642) explains why. (kernel 5.1.7)